# High-charts with data coming from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, highcharts

I am currently creating a Money management system, the idea is that the user inputs data and it gets visualized by a High charts area chart. I currently have a working version that is gathering data from the DB, this was done by following this tutorial: https://blueflame-software.com/area-chart-with-data-from-mysql-using-highcharts/

This code is set up to receive 4 pieces of data from the database the Month, Income, Expenditure, Subscriptions, inside income/exp/sub is just numbers. I wish to change the database so that Income/exp/sub is all under the 1 heading of Trans_Type, and the amount of each is under Trans_Amount.

My question is how would I change the actual PHP code given in the example below to suit a MySQL query of for example "`SELECT Month, Trans_Amount, Trans_Type 'Income', 'Expenditure', 'Subscriptions' FROM transactions WHERE UserID=".$_SESSION['user'])`

My Current working PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Month, Income, Expenditure , Subscriptions FROM     transactions WHERE UserID=".$_SESSION['user']);

$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Month';

$series1 = array();
$series1['Amount'] = 'Income';

$series2 = array();
$series2['name'] = 'Expenditure';

$series3 = array();
$series3['name'] = 'Subscriptions';


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$category['data'][] = $r['Month'];
$series1['data'][] = $r['Income'];
$series2['data'][] = $r['Expenditure'];
$series3['data'][] = $r['Subscriptions'];   
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);
array_push($result,$series2);
array_push($result,$series3);


print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: *how would I change the actual JS code given in the example below* ... did you forget to post the JS code? all I see is PHP

Comment: no sorry i meant to say how would i change the PHP code